# Proof of equation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Suppose, $E_1, E_2, E_3$ and $E_4$ are subsets of a universal set $E$ such that $E_1\subseteq E_2$ and $E_4\subseteq E_3$. Then,  $(E_1\cap E_3) \cup (E_2\cap E_4)=E_2\cap E_3$.

It is observed that any counter examples we take sayisfy this equation, but unable to establish a formal proof of this.

**Edit:** the above equation is incorrect  but $(E_1\cap E_3)\cup (E_2\cap E_4)\subseteq E_2 \cap E_3$ holds. So, the question should have been under what conditions, the above equality will hold?

Comment: A counterexample will not satisfy the equation.  Do you think it is true and want to prove it, or do you think there is a counterexample and it is false?  Why?  What have you tried?  I would make a truth table.  There are only $16$ lines.  Where are the parentheses on the left of the last equation?  I suspect they will matter.  More common is\cap for intersection and \cup for union, which give $\cap$ and $\cup$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(E_1\cap E_3)\cup (E_2\cap E_4)\subseteq E_1 \cup E_4.$

So for $(E_1\cap E_3)\cup (E_2\cap E_4)= E_2 \cap E_3$ to hold, $E_2 \cap E_3 \subseteq E_1 \cup E_4 $ must hold.

In addition. $E_1 \subseteq E_2$ and $E_4 \subseteq E_3$,
$E_1 \cap E_4 \subseteq E_1\cap E_3$ and  $E_1 \cap E_4 \subseteq E_2\cap E_4$
So $E_1 \cap E_4 \subseteq (E_1\cap E_3)\cup (E_2\cap E_4)$

Therefore if  $E_2 \cap E_3 = E_1 \cap E_4 $ holds, then $(E_1\cap E_3)\cup (E_2\cap E_4)= E_2 \cap E_3$ also holds.

Comment: your condition in the last statement is not a sufficient condition . Or, can you elaborate your point?

Comment: Ok. Instead of equality sub graph relation $\subseteq $ can also be used in general.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** For subset relationship,
It's pretty easy to see that both $E_1\cdot E3$ and $E2\cdot E4$ are subsets of $E2\cdot E3$.
Therefore their union is also a subset of $E2\cdot E3$.

Comment: Ok. Later i realised that instead of equality, there should be $\subseteq$ relation.

Comment: Yes, to show the subset equal relationship is easy but my question now is under what conditions, the equality in the original question holds?